# Build separate CSS files using Tailwindcss and laravel-vite-plugin

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, vite

I'm trying to build two separate CSS files using Tailwindcss, Laravel and vite-plugin.
The two css files use different configuration, but I have no idea how specify the correct **tailwind.config.js** for each builds.

- **app.css** should use **tailwind.config.js**
- **mail.css** should use **tailwind-mail.config.js**

**vite.config.js**

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin"

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ["resources/css/app.css", "resources/js/app.js", "resources/css/mail.css"]
            refresh: true,
        })
    ]
})
```

**postcss.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './vendor/laravel/jetstream/**/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
    ],
    theme: {},
    plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/forms"), require("@tailwindcss/typography")],
}
```

**tailwind-mail.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    content: ["./resources/views/mails/**/*.blade.php"],
    theme: {},
    plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/typography")],
}
```

Comment: Trying to also figure this out. Haven't been able to find anything online related to vite since the original article was for webpack. Please create an answer if you managed to figure it out.

Comment: @m33ts4k0z Sorry, I haven't figured this out yet.

Comment: @m33ts4k0z I think the release of Tailwind CSS 3.2 will solve this issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't try myself *yet*, but reading the [release notes](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3-2#multiple-config-files-in-one-project-using-config) of Tailwind CSS v3.2 it should be fairly easy to split into two CSS files using `@config <filename>`:

**app.css**

```css
@config "./tailwind.config.js";
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**mail.css**

```css
@config "./tailwind.mail.config.js";
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**vite.config.js**

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin"

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ["resources/css/app.css", "resources/js/app.js", "resources/css/mail.css"]
            refresh: true,
        })
    ]
})
```

Comment: @config "./tailwind.mail.config.js"; missing semicolon